# lambda function returning a list of None elements

Tags: python, lambda

does anyone know why the function fill the list with "None"?
I can not find the problem, everything looks true.

```
my_lis = []
l = lambda m : [my_lis.append(x) for x in range(m)]
l(10) 

output : [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

if i print the x instead of append,  i get 1 to 10 and the None list at the end.
anyway I'm trying to get a list of numbers by this way

Comment: `append` return `none`. try list comprehension : `l = lambda m : [x for x in range(m)]`

Comment: Why don't just use List Comp directly - ```lst = [x for x in range(10) ]``` Like ^^^ indicated ```append``` is in-place ops.  Should not do that!

Comment: `create_list = lambda limit : list(range(limit))`

Comment: Note that `my_list` is actually correctly filled (try printing it)! It's just that the output of your function ISN'T `my_list` .

Comment: No real need for a function for something like this since `list(range(10))` is easy enough to type and clearer than using a lambda function to mutate a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple list comprehension

```py
lst = [i**2 for i in range(3)]
```

is interpreted as:

```py
lst = []
for i in range(3):
    lst.append(i**2)
```

Now back to your example: So your code is currently like this:

```py
my_lis = []

def l(m):
    result = []
    for x in range(m):
        result.append(my_lis.append(x))
    return result


print(l(10))  # [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
print(my_lis) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

So basically you're filling the `my_lis` when you call `my_lis.append()`, but `.append()` is an in-place method, It just adds item to the list but its return value is `None` and you're filling `result` with `None`s. Indeed `result` is the what list comprehension hands you after-all.

---

As per request in comment:

You basically don't need extra `my_lis` list. The list comprehension inside the lambda gives you the final result, so:

```py
l = lambda m: [x for x in range(m)]
print(l(10))
```

Now `[x for x in range(m)]` is pointless and slower here, You can directly call `list` on `range(m)`:

```py
l = lambda m: list(range(m))
print(l(10))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.i'm trying to write it with lamba, is it possible to show me how to write this code using lambda and one line for loop?